# Git octopus merge - does the order of the refs matter

Tags: git, git-merge

When performing an octopus merge with Git, you provide more than 1 ref to be merged (here `fixes` and `enhancements`):

```
$ git merge fixes enhancements
```

Does it make any difference if the provided refs are in a different order, e.g.

```
$ git merge enhancements fixes
```

I expect no, because the octopus merge seems to be one that rejects conflicts for the same file, but different refs.

Comment: The order should be irrelevant. I'm not sure what you mean by "same file but different refs" in that last sentence, though.